# VCR auto-rerecord not rerecording after first interval

Tags: ruby, mechanize, vcr

I have a problem with auto rerecording of cassettes in vcr

This is my config:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/support/vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :fakeweb
end
```

and the call:

```
VCR.use_cassette 'my_cassette', :re_record_interval => 60 * 30 do
   agent = Mechanize.new
   start_page = agent.get(START_PAGE)
end
```

for the first request the cassette is recorded correctly but after the interval time passes for the first time it doesn't rerecord the cassette, it just appends new request data to the file, ignoring the interval completely.

Comment: What is the 60 * 30? Is the re_record_internal in seconds?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `re_record_interval` is working as it was designed to work, but it may not be what you want.

When you use the `:re_record_interval` option, VCR forces the `:record` mode to `:all` if enough time has passed.  In this record mode, it allows all HTTP requests to be made for real and records them. When it persists what was recorded to disk, it merges the new HTTPInteractions with the previously recorded ones, removing any old interactions for which there is a matching new interaction (based on your `:match_requests_on` option).  This is how `:all` is designed to work because there's no guarantee a particular cassette is only used on place in your test suite, and so it could be used like this:

```
it 'makes a request to /foo' do
  VCR.use_cassette("some-host") do
    make_request_to("http://some-host.com/foo")
  end
end

it 'makes a request to /bar' do
  VCR.use_cassette("some-host", :record => :all) do
    make_request_to("http://some-host.com/bar")
  end
end
```

In this situation, when you the `it "makes a request to /bar"` test runs, it will allow the request to be made for real and record it, and when persisting it to disk it will take the place of any previously recorded HTTP requests to `"http://some-host.com/bar"`, but it will leave any other previously recorded HTTP interactions (such as the one to `"http://some-host.com/foo"`) because it doesn't want to remove HTTP interactions that are not involved in this test (and thus may be used by an entirely different test).

Comment: Yes but, after one interval passes it just doesn't use the interval any more. it just rerecords every time. to make it clear: first time it records the cassette and then before the interval is passed it uses the cassette. after that it just issues new http requests and rerecords the cassettes. it doesn't use cassettes any more.

Comment: That could be a bug then.  Can you put together an example and file an issue on the VCR issue tracker?

Comment: Yes apparently it was A bug. updating vcr solved the problem.